# style sheet rule application

Tags: jquery, css

Using JQuery mobile 1.3.2 I am having trouble setting the style of some links.  I don't want all links to look the same, so some will use one style while others will use a different one.  I have attempted to add my own custom class, and to even override the JQuery style; however, both attempts have been unsuccessful.

I have created http://jsfiddle.net/qdz9b/1/ to help illustrate my issue.

Custom stylesheet (Loaded after jquery css)

```
.ui-link{color:#000000;}
.ui-link:visited{color:#000000}
.myLink{color:#000000;}
.aDifferentLink{color:#FF0000;}

.myImportantLink{color:#000000 !important;}
```

The HTML

```
<a href="#test">basic link, no custom class</a><br/>
<a href="#test" class="myLink">link with custom class, not working either.</a><br/>
<a href="#test" class="aDifferentLink">a different link, should be red. not working either.</a><br/>
<br>
<a href="#test" class="myImportantLink">link with !important class, the only way I can get it to work.</a><br/>
```

Rendered HTML

```
<a href="#test" class="ui-link">basic link, no custom class</a>
<a href="#test" class="myLink ui-link">link with custom class, not working either.</a>
<a href="#test" class="aDifferentLink ui-link">a different link, should be red. not working either.</a>
<a href="#test" class="myImportantLink ui-link">link with !important class, the only way I can get it to work.</a>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About how CSS rules are applied, you can read this article:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa062706.htm

In short, priority of `.ui-body-c .ui-link` (from jquery-mobile.css) is higher than just `.myLink` (your custom css style). And `!important` forces specified css rule to be applied.

here's the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qdz9b/2/